# Combining rows with naming subsets

Tags: r

I have a large `data.frame` (over 44,000 rows) which I have managed to `aggregate` into 128 rows that include my analysis `Section` and the sum of cells within that section presented as `Count`, an example of which looks like the following:

```
  Section   Count
  A - 2-1    10
  A - 2-2     2
  A - 2-3    39
  A - 2-4    31
  A - 2-5    42
  A - 2-6     1
  A - 2-7     9
  A - 2-8     4
  A - 2-9     2
  A - 3-1    52
  A - 3-2    27
  A - 3-3    42
  A - 3-4   107
  A - 3-5     6
  A - 3-6    51
  A - 3-7   155
  A - 3-8     5
  A - 3-9    13
```

I have looked at related topics but they all deal with having the same ID tag that makes it easy to group. What I want to do is to further aggregate so I can combine all of my `Sections` (e.g A-2) that have multiple fields (A-2-1, A-2-2, etc...) to give me a total cell `Count`, so that it appears as follows:

```
  Section       Count
  A - 2           140
  A - 3           458
```

I've been trying various ways of doing this based on other threads but cannot get any to work, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dplyr` package `your_data_frame %>% group_by(Section) %>% summarise(Count2=sum(Count))`

Comment: @MikolajM please post it as an answer

Comment: just realised that there is no column for (fld x) thing so this wont work

Comment: @MikolajM If there is some `(fld x)` thing which you need to ignore then `df %>% group_by(sub("\\(.*", "", Section) %>% summarise(Count2=sum(Count))` should do it.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about something like `spread(Section, sep=" ")` and then `unite()` the first two columns to do `group_by()` on their basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$Section = substr(df$Section,1,nchar(df$Section)-2)
## df$Section = substr(df$Section, start = 1, stop = 3) # alt option
aggregate(df$Count, by=list(Section=df$Section), FUN=sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this serves to give me the same output.    `Frequency    x
1   A - 2 (fld 1)   10
2   A - 2 (fld 2)    2
3   A - 2 (fld 3)   39`

Comment: I modified my code for your original data and now I noted that you have a different `Section` column. See if it works now.

Comment: You are an absolute legend thanks so much for that!